# Start Animation from last state it ends CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, css-animations

```js
var app = angular.module('dialApp', ['ngAnimate']);

angular.module('dialApp').controller('MainController',['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.test = 'Test';

  $scope.left = false;
  $scope.right = false;
  $scope.bottom = false;
  $scope.leftRotate = function () {
    $scope.left = true;
    $scope.right = false;
    $scope.bottom = false;
  }

  $scope.rightRotate = function () {
    $scope.left = false;
    $scope.right = true;
    $scope.bottom = false;
  }

  $scope.bottomRotate = function () {
    $scope.left = false;
    $scope.right = false;
    $scope.bottom = true;
  }

}]);
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.panel-default {
  border-color: #EFF7FA;
}

.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: large;
  background-color: #EFF7FA;
}

.panel-body {
  background-color: #E7F0F4;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle {
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid #ffa003;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease-out, transform 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease-out, transform 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 1s ease-out, transform 1s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 1s ease-out, transform 1s ease-out;
}

.circle:hover {
  background-color: #ffa003;
  cursor: pointer;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  /* Safari */
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  /* Standard syntax */
}

.active-circle {
  background-color: #ffa003;
  cursor: pointer;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  /* Safari */
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  /* Standard syntax */
}

.p-1 {
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.p-2 {
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.center-element {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  /* margin-left: -120px; */
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.dial {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  /*top: 25px;*/
  /*animation: rotate 60s infinite steps(60);*/
}


.dial:before {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/GmzAbGi.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  top: -19%;
  right: 29%;
}

.dailKnob {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  top: 25%;
  left: 170px;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 43%;
  /*animation: rotate 60s infinite steps(60);*/
}

.rotate90 {
  -webkit-animation: rotate90d 1.0s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz--animation: rotate90d 1.0s forwards;
  -moz--animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -o-animation: rotate90d 1.0s forwards;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.3);
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.rotate180 {
  -webkit-animation: rotate180d 1.0s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz--animation: rotate90d 1.0s forwards;
  -moz--animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -o-animation: rotate90d 1.0s forwards;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.3);
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) scale(1.3);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(180deg) scale(1.3);
  -o-transform:      rotate(180deg) scale(1.3);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(180deg) scale(1.3);*/
}

.rotate270 {
  -webkit-animation: rotate270d 1.0s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz--animation: rotate90d 1.0s forwards;
  -moz--animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -o-animation: rotate90d 1.0s forwards;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.3);
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) scale(1.3);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(270deg) scale(1.3);
  -o-transform:      rotate(270deg) scale(1.3);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(270deg) scale(1.3);*/
}


@keyframes rotate90d {
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate180d {
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate270d {
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(270deg);
  }
}


.sides {
  margin-top: 7%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<body ng-app="dialApp">
  <div class="container col-xs-12" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="height: 100%">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <p class="panel-heading">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce tortor nunc, dapibus et est ut, maximus vehicula ipsum. Pellentesque orci purus, maximus eget eros eu, elementum mattis elit. Vivamus leo lacus, hendrerit id fringilla et, accumsan nec ligula.Ut pulvinar odio massa, vitae molestie eros consectetur non. Vivamus nunc lectus, consectetur id ullamcorper venenatis, rutrum in urna. Vestibulum at risus diam.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 10px;">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom: 60px;">
            <div class="col-xs-2 sides" >
              <b class="p-1">Yes </b>
              <div class="circle" style="float: left;" ng-class="{ 'active-circle' : left }" ng-click="leftRotate()"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
              <div class="image-container" style="width: 400px;">
                <!--  <img src="images/selectionArrow.png" class="arrow">-->
                <div class="dial center-element" ng-class="{'rotate270' : left ,'rotate90' : right,'rotate180' : bottom }">
                  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/fVrS3hS.png">
                </div>
                <img class="dailKnob" src="http://i.imgur.com/VrnjQcT.png">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 sides" >
              <div class="circle" style="float: left;" ng-class="{ 'active-circle' : right }" ng-click="rightRotate()"></div>
              <b class="p-2">No</b>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="col-xs-2 sides">
              &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
              <div class="image-container" style="width: 400px;">
                <div class="circle center-element" ng-class="{ 'active-circle' : bottom }" ng-click="bottomRotate()"></div>
                <div class="center-element" ><b>May be</b></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              &nbsp;
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ou5bucYMDYdIOFUUAZeH?p=preview

I want create it like clock type animation..
in this when user click  on NO -> arrow will go to close with animation
then when user click on May Be... it would start from No to  May be ..
But now..it start from first frame..same for may be to yes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `css-transition` instead of `css-animation`

1. For the `.dial` element set `transition:all 1s ease;` (Or custom it as you need).
2. For the `.rotate90`, `.rotate180` and `.rotate270` instead of animation replace it to `transform: rotateZ(your_deg);`

Like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('dialApp', ['ngAnimate']);

angular.module('dialApp').controller('MainController',['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.test = 'Test';

  $scope.left = false;
  $scope.right = false;
  $scope.bottom = false;
  $scope.leftRotate = function () {
    $scope.left = true;
    $scope.right = false;
    $scope.bottom = false;
  }

  $scope.rightRotate = function () {
    $scope.left = false;
    $scope.right = true;
    $scope.bottom = false;
  }

  $scope.bottomRotate = function () {
    $scope.left = false;
    $scope.right = false;
    $scope.bottom = true;
  }

}]);
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.panel-default {
  border-color: #EFF7FA;
}

.panel-default > .panel-heading {
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: large;
  background-color: #EFF7FA;
}

.panel-body {
  background-color: #E7F0F4;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle {
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid #ffa003;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease-out, transform 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease-out, transform 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 1s ease-out, transform 1s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 1s ease-out, transform 1s ease-out;
}

.circle:hover {
  background-color: #ffa003;
  cursor: pointer;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  /* Safari */
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  /* Standard syntax */
}

.active-circle {
  background-color: #ffa003;
  cursor: pointer;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  /* Safari */
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  /* Standard syntax */
}

.p-1 {
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.p-2 {
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.center-element {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  /* margin-left: -120px; */
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.dial {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  /* this element will animate because of this */
  transition:all 1s ease;
}


.dial:before {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/GmzAbGi.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  top: -19%;
  right: 29%;
}

.dailKnob {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  top: 25%;
  left: 170px;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 43%;
}

.rotate90 {
  /* use transform instead animation */
  transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}

.rotate180 {
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}

.rotate270 {
  transform: rotateZ(270deg);
}

.sides {
  margin-top: 7%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<body ng-app="dialApp">
  <div class="container col-xs-12" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="height: 100%">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <p class="panel-heading">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce tortor nunc, dapibus et est ut, maximus vehicula ipsum. Pellentesque orci purus, maximus eget eros eu, elementum mattis elit. Vivamus leo lacus, hendrerit id fringilla et, accumsan nec ligula.Ut pulvinar odio massa, vitae molestie eros consectetur non. Vivamus nunc lectus, consectetur id ullamcorper venenatis, rutrum in urna. Vestibulum at risus diam.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 10px;">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6" style="height: 120px; margin-bottom: 60px;">
            <div class="col-xs-2 sides" >
              <b class="p-1">Yes </b>
              <div class="circle" style="float: left;" ng-class="{ 'active-circle' : left }" ng-click="leftRotate()"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
              <div class="image-container" style="width: 400px;">
                <!--  <img src="images/selectionArrow.png" class="arrow">-->
                <div class="dial center-element" ng-class="{'rotate270' : left ,'rotate90' : right,'rotate180' : bottom }">
                  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/fVrS3hS.png">
                </div>
                <img class="dailKnob" src="http://i.imgur.com/VrnjQcT.png">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 sides" >
              <div class="circle" style="float: left;" ng-class="{ 'active-circle' : right }" ng-click="rightRotate()"></div>
              <b class="p-2">No</b>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="col-xs-2 sides">
              &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
              <div class="image-container" style="width: 400px;">
                <div class="circle center-element" ng-class="{ 'active-circle' : bottom }" ng-click="bottomRotate()"></div>
                <div class="center-element" ><b>May be</b></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              &nbsp;
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My pleasure.. Good luck!